# Tapestry: How to overlay DateField pop-up over jquery/dat​atable

Tags: jquery, datatable, overlay, tapestry, datefield

When I have a DateField component above a grid, the DateField pop-up(calendar style) overlays the grid. However, when I use jquery/datatable, the DateField pop-up is obstructed by the datatable. How can I have the DateField pop-up overlays the datatable?

Here is my tml file

```
<input t:type="DateField" t:id="DateTo" value="dateToValue" format="MM/dd/yyyy"     t:validate="required" />      
<table width="100%" t:type="jquery/datatable" t:id="list" t:source="dataList" t:row="rowData"  t:options="options"
```

Comment: can you share your code on JSFiddle?

Comment: I have edited my post and added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) issue to me. You will need to ensure that the DateField's popup has a larger z-index than the jquery datatable.  Most browsers have a feature where you can right click on a UI element and inspect it. You can then see what CSS classes are applying to the datefield popup. Then, add a CSS rule to increase the z-index.

```
.whateverclass {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```